# Base64 decoding error on Android project (java)

Tags: java, android, base64

I use this code on my Android app to protect my public key:

```
    private static String xorDecrypt(String input, String key) {
    byte[] inputBytes = Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT);
    int inputSize = inputBytes.length;

    byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes();
    int keySize = keyBytes.length - 1;

    byte[] outBytes = new byte[inputSize];
    for (int i=0; i<inputSize; i++) {
        outBytes[i] = (byte) (inputBytes[i] ^ keyBytes[i % keySize]);
    }

    return new String(outBytes);
}
```

On some device this works without problem but on some device I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.myname.myapp.a.b: Bad Base64 input character at 160:      -65(decimal)
at com.myname.myapp.a.s.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myname.myapp.a.s.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myname.myapp.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myname.myapp.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myname.myapp.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myname.myapp.a.f.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: com.myname.myapp.a.b: Bad Base64 input character at 160: -65(decimal)
at com.myname.myapp.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myname.myapp.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myname.myapp.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

I think the problem is the xorDecrypt function because I use the base64 function only this.

How can I avoid it?

This error force close my app.

Answer (score 0):

check before decoding, it might help:

```
if(Base64.isBase64(input)){
Base64.decodeBase64(input);
}
```

Comment: Android Studio say: "cannot resolve method isBase64"

Comment: Ok, I guess you are using `android.util.Base64`, if feasible for you I'd suggest using `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` which offers more utility methods, also I think android is not fully compatible with apache commons, to use apache in android have a look at `https://github.com/smannlymann/ApacheCommonsIO-for-Android`, if it is feasible for you